# F# ViewModel not instantiated via BindingContext in XAML

Tags: f#, xamarin.forms

I am unable to observe a viewmodel within my F# library get instantiated via a ContextBinding within XAML.

Instead, I only observe my app hanging (i.e. black screen).

**NOTE:**

I am unable to reference the actual F# project (which is a PCL) that harbors the viewmodel. As a workaround, I browsed to the path of the DLL (i.e. bin\debug) that contains the viewmodel instead.

While troubleshooting, I did observe that a viewmodel within a C# project get instantiated. However, a viewmodel within my F# project does not.

**My XAML is the following:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:home="clr-namespace:Home.ViewModels;assembly=Home"
             x:Class="FnTrade.MainPage">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <home:HomeViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
</ContentPage>
```

**My viewmodel within the F# project is the following:**

```
namespace Home.ViewModels

type HomeViewModel() =

    let foo = "Hello World" // Breakpoint never gets hit
```

**My viewmodel does get instantiated via XAML when referencing a C# implementation:**

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FnTrade;assembly=FnTrade"
             x:Class="FnTrade.MainPage">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:ViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
</ContentPage>
```

**Here's the viewmodel in C#:**

```
namespace FnTrade
{
    public class ViewModel
    {
        public ViewModel() { } // Breakpoint DOES get hit
    }
}
```

Can someone explain to me why my viewmodel written in F# does not get instantiated?

Answer (score 2):

I added **FSharp.Core** to both my Xamarin.Forms project as well as my platform project (i.e. Droid).

I also ensured that an **app.config** file was in both projects as well.

I updated the *app.config* file to the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="FSharp.Core" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
                          culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.999.999.999" newVersion="4.4.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Didn't you have a similar problem before?

Comment: Yes. However, helpful exceptions were being swallowed as a result of having a XAML dependency. I discovered the issue while using code-behind to troubleshoot.

Comment: Note that this is often easier to diagnose if you construct the type in code, not xaml

Comment: Yep. I realized that after going bald.